# Connecting two vagrant machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am currently attempting to connect two vagrant environments. One is a web application with an associated postgres database. The other is an API application which makes calls to the postgres database on the first vagrant machine. Can anyone provide advice as to how this can be achieved. I believe I will need to change my database.yml or envirornment.rb file but not quite sure how. My vagrantfiles and database.yml files are currently like so:

Front-End Machine Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../api", "/API"
end
```

Front-End Machine database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chsh

development: &development
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  username: username
  password: password
  database: database_name
  pool: 10
```

API Machine:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3002, host: 3002
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read the code, I didn't see any way to configure multiple machines.

You can bypass this by reconfiguring before use..

```
module Vagrant

  def set(name)
    send(name) if respond_to?(name)
  end

  def front_end
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
      config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base"
      config.vm.synced_folder "../api", "/API"
    end
  end

  def api
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3002, host: 3002
      config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base"
      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You will be then able to do something like this:

```
Vagrant.set(:front_end)
Vagrant.set(:api)
```

Comment: Where would i reconfigure this? Is this a modified vagrantfile. Structure just seems a bit different.